# DateTime picker in Win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I want to **disable the past days in date time picker control**...they must be appear on the calender  but they are in disable state.I am tried...but the all past days are disappeared from the calender.any idea..
My code is:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Use Following :

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(year, month,day);
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = new DateTime(year, month,day);
dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd";
```

To disable Days before the first day of current month:

```
dateTimePicker1.MinDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
```

Limit Future Date :

`MaxDate` is used as follows

```
dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(number of days);
```